# Running build using jenkins cli hangs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm attempting to run a jenkins build using the cli with the following command:

```
java -jar /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jenkins/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://104.197.65.80:5001/jenkins/ build github-test -sv
```

However the command just hangs indefinitely with no error and the build is never kicked off in jenkins.

Update:
The TCP port for JNLP agents was configured for 5001:
[image]

I restarted the vm after making that change, but it looks like there is still nothing listening on 5001:

> opike99@jenkins-1-vm:~$ nc -z -v -w5 104.197.99.99 5001 < /dev/null
>   99.99.197.104.bc.googleusercontent.com [104.197.99.99] 5001 (?) : Connection timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-s` parameter should be the URL to the Jenkins web UI.  Remove the `:5001` suffix and it will work.

You don't need to provide the JNLP port — the CLI client needs to work also when the port number is random, so it [asks the Jenkins web server](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#using-the-cli) for the port number.

Comment: That did it - thanks. I also needed to add --username and --passoword:
java -jar $CLASSPATH/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<ip>/jenkins/ list-jobs --username <username> --password <password>